# What could be wrong running django locally, in terms of session caching?

Tags: python, django, memcached, django-redis, saleor

There seems to be a problem with redis, even though i've ran the same application successfully with the same django settings.

In settings.py, my database settings are as such:

**

```
if os.environ.get('REDIS_URL'):  
    CACHES['default'] = {
        'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': os.environ.get('REDIS_URL')}

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(
        default='postgres://localhost:5432/saleor',
        conn_max_age=600)}
```

**

I get this error:

**saleor.W001: Session caching cannot work with locmem backend
    HINT: User sessions need to be globally shared, use a cache server like Redis.**

Comment: Have you actually set a REDIS_URL environment variable?

Comment: No I didn't do this, thank you. So added this to my .bash_profile :         
                                                                                                               export REDIS_URL=/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-package/django-redis

Comment: But that's not a URL. You need the address that Redis is listening on - probably localhost:6379.

Comment: Yes you are right, really helped...thank you :)